# How to copy keys and values of map to set of pair

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, set

Hello all i am trying  to transfer my data from the map to the set of pair
that's my test code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>




using namespace std;

int main() {


    string command;

    int resource;
   map<string, int> map;
   set< pair<string, int> > s;

   while (std::cin >> command && command != "stop" && std::cin >> resource)
    {
        map[command] += resource;

    }


    return 0;
}
```

When the while loop finish and the map is filled. How to transfer the data or copy it to the set of pair ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Define set after the loop by: `set< pair<string, int> > s{map.begin(),map.end()};`

Answer (score 2):

The set constructor actually handles this all for you, so you can just do:

```
std::set<std::pair<std::string, int>> s(m.begin(), m.end());
```

See it in action here: https://ideone.com/Do0LOW

(Also, you probably shouldn't name your variable `map` the same as a type. This is even more of an issue when you're `using namespace std` like that).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `set` [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/set) that takes the map as a range.

```
std::set<std::pair<std::string, int>> s {map.begin(), map.end()};
```

If your set already exists, then you can use `copy`.

```
std::copy(map.begin(), map.end(), std::inserter(s, s.end()));
```

Comment: Thank you to all it works. But my idea was that getting input for example  John  23     Peter 44  and Rick  65 and i want to transfer it to set in this order like the input and print it in the same way ?  But i cant figure out how to make its not working and with set of pair ?

Comment: Seems like you need `unordered_map`, and `unordered_set`.

Comment: Why i need  unordered_map or unordered_set ? i cant understand  i choose set  because i need unique elements

Comment: You'll get unique elements either way. In the `unordered_` versions, the unique elements are in the order they were inserted.

Comment: @cigien `In the unordered_ versions, the unique elements are in the order they were inserted` No. As the name implies, the elements are unordered.

Comment: See @eerorika's comment, it's correct. If you want a specific order, then you could use `vector<pair<string,int>>`. You will have to maintain uniqueness yourself though.

Comment: @Who123 Also in addition to cigien's comment, the elements in the map are ordered by the key, so if you copy from the map to the vector, the order is not the order in which elements were inserted into the map. You'd need to insert directly into the vector.

Comment: @Who123 You can potentially use multiple containers. You can use vector to keep the insertion order, and use a set to check whether a new element should be added to avoid breaking uniqueness.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help

Comment: @Who123 If this answers your question, consider accepting it.

Comment: yes i made it that's what i  made  https://pastebin.com/y1JnpuGc